# Adding huawei auth to exiting app that uses firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, huawei-mobile-services

I have an already existing flutter app that uses firebase auth, MLVision for face recognition and cloud messaging for push notification. I'm using flutter. My problem now is how to integrate Huawei auth. I'm new with this huawei integration. I haven't tried it yet, I just want to know before starting.

From what I've read from some post. I need to integrate
Huawei Mobile Services (HMS),
Huawei Account Kit and AppGallery Connect Auth Service.
For non huawei phone with google services, I can authenticate using both firebase and huawei auth with different button right? But how about huawei phones without google services?

1. How will the app know? So it can hide the firebase login or run huawei only scripts for authenticaion?
2. MLVision needs google play services. Is there the same for huawei kit?
3. If its a large revision of code, will it be easier to create the app only for huawei phone with HMS, auth, Pushkit and with no google services script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How will the app know? So it can hide the firebase login or run huawei only scripts for authenticaion?

You can refer this plug-in:https://pub.dev/packages/google_api_availability

The HMS will also provide a plug-in for determining the availability of the HMS in the near future. You can also use the plug-in at that time.

> MLVision needs google play services. Is there the same for huawei kit?

The [ML Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050040017?ha_source=hms1) of the HMS also provides the facial recognition function.

For the FLutter platform, pls kindly refer the following link:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/body-related-services-0000001074129424?ha_source=hms1

> If its a large revision of code, will it be easier to create the app only for huawei phone with HMS, auth, Pushkit and with no google services script.

The HMS plug-in interface is not mapped to the GMS interface, and the implementation logic is different. Therefore, one-to-one mapping cannot be implemented. Many kits are involved,so the compatibility development will change greatly. You are advised to develop it separately to improve efficiency.